# Google translate API OAuth2 scope issue

Tags: oauth-2.0, scope, translate, google-docs-api

In my project I'm using the translating google API and it worked fine for few months.

Now, I'm getting the following error message :

> Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
> code : 403
> status : PERMISSION_DENIED
> reason : ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT

In the oauth2 authentication call, I gived this scope parameter :
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-translation

It works when I replace with this one :
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform

But I don't know why I needed to do a change, because it's just an api call for translate text and it worked perfectly until last week.

Documentation for scopes here :
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#translate